# Pass variable with Symfony2 constrains

Tags: symfony, annotations, constraints

I'm trying to validate if two emails are equal each other, by using the annotation constraint "EqualTo". But, EqualTo is case sensitve, and alot of our users write emails with big and small letters.

Therefore am I  trying to 'tolower' the user input, by slightly editting the EqualTo function and renamed it for test purposes to "ToLowerEqualTo".

The constraints:

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(max=100)
 * @Assert\Email(
 *        message = "The email '{{ value }}' isn't valid",
 *        checkMX = false
 * )
 */
public $email;   // ( someemail@gmail.com)

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(max=100)
 * @Assert\ToLowerEqualTo(
 *     "email",
 *      message = "The email '{{ value }}' doesn't match"
 * )
 */
public $confirmEmail;  // (SomeEmail@gmail.com)
```

### #

The ToLowerEqualToValidator:

```
protected function compareValues($value1, $value2)
{
     $lowerValue1 = strtolower($value1);
     $lowerValue2 = strtolower($value2);
     return $lowerValue1 == $lowerValue2;
}
```

$Value1 is correctly equal to SomeEmail@gmail.com
$Value2 is wrongly equal to "email", instead of "someemail@gmail.com".

So the question, How do I pass the $email variable in my ToLowerEqualTo constraint function ?

Comment: Did you get the two emails when using just IsEqual?  Because I'm pretty sure you cannot pass a property as an argument.  You might need something like: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#getters or perhaps just use the repeated form type: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html

Comment: No, I tho I tried with with Expression which seems ok: 
* @Assert\Expression(
     *     "this.confirmEmail == this.email",
     *     message="Emailadresserne matcher ikke."
     * )